PHP How to catch specific "$x must be array" exception in try/catch?
I'm trying to send a specific error message to our error logger regarding the context of an error that occurs specifically because a variable being passed to array_key_exists is not an array. I want to be really specific in my error message so I want to have a catch that specifically returns some info about the context ONLY when that particular $x is not an array exception occurs, but I can't figure out how to specifically look for that exception, is there a way?
So for example, I have:
try {
    // blah blah some stuff
    array_key_exists('blah', $maybeAnArray)
    // blah blah more stuff
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    logger()->error($e);
    // send notification that says $maybeAnArray is not an array because of blah blah, do something about it when you see this error
}

Only in the case above, that Exception $e would be caught for ANY exception not only for the array exception.
Is there a way to do something like you would with an if statement where you'd do something like:
if(!is_array($maybeAnArray) {
    // throw Exception $e and log error with specific details
}

Thanks!

Try catching TypeError instead of Exception.

The fact that you know that $maybeAnArray could possibly not be an array, tells me that it is not an exceptional case, it is known, You can still log things and send emails, that's fine, but I don't see a need to invoke and deal with exceptions. Is there a reason that you want to avoid the very simple if language construct and replace it with something more complex?

@ChrisHaas maybe i'm overthinking it, essentially I want to send all errors to the error logger UNLESS it's the "not an array" issue, in which case it's on the TBD tech debt pile regarding a deprecated instance of something we're not using anymore, and those 'not an array' issues are clogging up our logs unnecessarily

Is it deprecated or unsupported? If the former, then presumably there's an existing path forward for a non-array. Continue down that path and consider using trigger_error with E_USER_DEPRECATED so that developers can still find it with advanced logging. If you don't do this, it is only "mental deprecated" which isn't helpful. If the latter, that's exceptional and presumably the code must die at that point?

Also, just throwing this out there, but would ?? solve this for you? https://3v4l.org/VcQbD

@ChrisHaas essentially it's an error caused by a tool we used a decade ago that left issues in the database that will be fixed when our content team eventually gets around to updating those items in the new CMS we're using, so basically something that's uselessly clogging up our logs until the content team gets to this task on the bottom of their to-do list hahaha. is it possible to check if Exception === TypeError or something? Because I don't want to stop ALL error logs, only ones where it isn't an array being passed

For me this boils down to "is/should this be fatal error or not". If it is not a fatal error, and you have a path forward, test with if, raise a deprecation warning and move on. If it is a fatal error, test with if and throw an exception, no need to log or use the try/catch.

Here is a working example of what you are trying to achieve.
<?php

// Simulate a logger function
function logger() {
    return new class {
        public function error($message) {
            echo "Logged Error: " . $message . "\n";
        }
    };
}

// Example function to demonstrate error handling
function checkArrayKey($maybeAnArray) {
    try {
        // Trying to use array_key_exists with $maybeAnArray
        array_key_exists('blah', $maybeAnArray);
        echo "array_key_exists executed successfully.\n";
    } catch (TypeError $e) {
        // Specific handling for when $maybeAnArray is not an array
        logger()->error("TypeError: \$maybeAnArray is not an array. Value: " . print_r($maybeAnArray, true));
        // You could do further processing or notification here
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Generic handling for other exceptions
        logger()->error("General Exception: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

// Test cases
$validArray = ['blah' => 'value'];
$invalidValue = "This is not an array";
$anotherInvalidValue = 12345;

// Calling the function with different types of inputs
echo "Test Case 1: Valid Array\n";
checkArrayKey($validArray); // Should execute without any errors

echo "\nTest Case 2: Invalid Value (String)\n";
checkArrayKey($invalidValue); // Should catch TypeError and log a specific message

echo "\nTest Case 3: Invalid Value (Integer)\n";
checkArrayKey($anotherInvalidValue); // Should catch TypeError and log a specific message

?>


for cli tests you can use this one liner:
php -r 'function logger() { return new class { public function error($message) { echo "Logged Error: " . $message . "\n"; } }; } function checkArrayKey($maybeAnArray) { try { array_key_exists("blah", $maybeAnArray); echo "array_key_exists executed successfully.\n"; } catch (TypeError $e) { logger()->error("TypeError: \$maybeAnArray is not an array. Value: " . print_r($maybeAnArray, true)); } catch (Exception $e) { logger()->error("General Exception: " . $e->getMessage()); } } echo "Test Case 1: Valid Array\n"; checkArrayKey(["blah" => "value"]); echo "\nTest Case 2: Invalid Value (String)\n"; checkArrayKey("This is not an array"); echo "\nTest Case 3: Invalid Value (Integer)\n"; checkArrayKey(12345);'

